# CodeEval Alphabet Blocks challenge

Tags: java, regex

I was working on a CodeEval challenge, here is it's description:

CHALLENGE DESCRIPTION:

We all remember those childhood times when we learned how to use alphabet blocks to form different words, such as MOM, DAD, TRAIN, and others. We propose you to remind this time for a while and imagine yourself being a child.
So, you have a set of alphabet blocks. There is a letter on each of the six faces of every block. Also, you have a word associated with your childhood that you want to form.
Write a program that will verify if it is possible to form the necessary word out of the set. If yes, then print "True" to stdout; otherwise, print "False".
You can choose only one letter from an alphabet block and place blocks in any order.

INPUT SAMPLE:

The first argument is a path to a file. Each line contains test cases that have three arguments separated by the pipe symbol "|". 
1. The first argument in the line is a number that shows how many blocks are in the set. 
2. The second one is a word that you want to form. 
3. The third one is a list of arrays of letters. One face of the alphabet block includes one letter from array. 
For example: 
There is an array of letters "ABCDEF". It refers to one toy block with the following faces: 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F".

```
4 | DOG | UPZRHR INOYLC KXDHNQ BAGMZI

6 | HAPPY | PKMFQP KTXGCV OSDMAJ SDSIMY OEPGLE JZCDHI

5 | PLAIN | BFUBZD XMQBNM IDXVCN JCOIAM OZYAYH
```

OUTPUT SAMPLE:

```
True
True
False
```

For some reason my code passed partially, can some one tell me what am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
public class AlphabetBlocks {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.trim();
        String[] separate = line.split(" \\| ");

        String[] blocks = separate[2].split("\\s+");
        separate[1] = separate[1].trim();

        for (int i = 0; i < separate[1].length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < blocks.length; j++) {
                if (blocks[j].contains(separate[1].toUpperCase().charAt(i)+"")) {
                    blocks[j]="";
                    separate[1] = separate[1].replaceFirst(separate[1].charAt(i)+"", "0");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (separate[1].matches("\\d+")) {
            System.out.println("True");
        } else {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets consider a 2-D matrix table for this question where -

- Rows equal size of the childhood string. Let's call this `n`.
- Cols equal total number of alphabet blocks. (4, 6, 5 in examples 1, 2 and 3). Lets call this `m`. They basically are the number of strings to be checked against.

In the `n x m` 2-D boolean matrix, if the `ith` character of the string is present in the `jth` block, we mark `table[i][j] = true;` Else it is marked as false. I've used the diagram below for the first example.

```
_ | UPZRHR | INOYLC | KXDHNQ | BAGMZI
D | false  | false  | true   | false
O | false  | true   | false  | false
G | false  | false  | false  | true
```

Now, a block can satisfy for all the letters of the childhood string. But for each and every character in the childhood string, we want a distinct alphabet block.

How do we go about this ?
Well, for every `table[i][j] = true`, we store `i` and `j` in 2 separate sets, `i` in the row set and `j` in the column set.

The size of the row-set should be exactly equal to the size of the childhood string. This means that every character in the childhood string is found in one of the alphabet blocks. 
The size of the column-set should be greater than or equal to the size of the childhood string. This means that we are able to make the string from distinct alphabet block.

If the above condition isn't satisfied we cannot make our childhood string.

Below is the function in c++. I've modified the way I take my input but the logic remains the same.

```
void solve() {
    string str; cin >> str; // chilhood string
    
    int n; cin >> n;
    
    vector<string> v(n);   // other strings
    for(string& s: v) cin >> s;
    
    // table
    vector<vector<bool>> dp(str.size(), vector<bool>(n, false));
    for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            dp[i][j] = (v[j].find(str[i]) != string::npos) ? true: false;
        }
    }
    
    unordered_set<int> row, col;
    for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            if(dp[i][j] == true) {
                row.insert(i);
                col.insert(j);
            }
        }
    }

    cout << ((row.size() == str.size() && col.size() >= str.size()) ? "true": "false") << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is a sample input where your code will not pass:

```
3 | DOG | DOXXXX DXXXXX GXXXXX
```

Your code will search and mark blocks sequentially. It will assign the first block to letter `D` rather than `O` and then there is no more blocks for `o`.

Maybe you could try searching the fewest word first